# no root file system on ubuntu 16 packer install

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, preseed, vagrant

I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a VirtualBox - Vagrant with Packer tool for auto creating and provisionning VM. When I launch my `packer build` command the auto install screen run correctly with boot command passed and question-response answer automatically.

But error is detected with partition disks config.

Can you help me to understand why and the part of my preseed or boot command file is false.

**screen error on VM :**

[image]

**The preseed.cfg file :**

```
# Ubuntu Server 16.04
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_GB.UTF-8
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select gb
d-i keyboard-configuration/layout string "United Kingdom"
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned
d-i mirror/country string UK
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string Europe/London
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true
d-i clock-setup/ntp-server string uk.pool.ntp.org
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/vda
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm_span boolean true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string sys_vg
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe atomic
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto/confirm boolean true
d-i passwd/root-login boolean false
d-i passwd/make-user boolean false
d-i passwd/user-fullname string tux
d-i passwd/username string tux
d-i passwd/user-password password Password1
d-i passwd/user-password-again password Password1
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect server, openssh-server
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server update-motd
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select none
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

**the boot command part of json packer :**

```
  "<enter><f6><esc>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
  "<bs><bs><bs>",
  "auto preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/test-preseed.cfg ",
  "debian-installer=en_CA locale=en_CA kbd-chooser/method=us ",
  "hostname=rails-5-jade ",
  "fb=false debconf/frontend=noninteractive ",
  "keyboard-configuration/modelcode=SKIP keyboard-configuration/layout=USA ",
  "keyboard-configuration/variant=USA console-setup/ask_detect=false ",
  "vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --- ",
  "<enter>"
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue with the QEMU builder of Packer. The problem in my case was, that I defined the line

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
```

in my preseed file, but Packer found no disk (same 'no file system' error as mentioned above). The line had to be changed to

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/vda
```

to work with QEMU.

Comment: I also had to adapt the " grub-installer/bootdev=/dev/sda<wait>", line in my "boot_command" argument for vda.